# How to call variable processed in forloop function (views) in django template?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to refer a variable `modela_completed` in my django template after some logic was applied to it.

Since it seems templates are only a place for making a page look nice, there must be a way to assign a value to a variable in a forloop and refer it into the template.

**models**

```
class ModelA(models.Model, HitCountMixin):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name",max_length=100, blank=True)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    
class ModelC(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="title",max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    venue = models.ManyToManyField(ModelA, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)

class ModelD(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(ModelC,null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="related_name")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    accepted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

**views**

```
def function(request, modeld_id):

    q_1 = ModelD.objects.get(pk=modeld_id)
    q_2 = q_1.name.modela.all()
    
    #count the number of q_2  in modelc
    modela_count = q_2 .count()
    
    modela_set = set()
    sum_completed = 0
    # identify date the ModelC was accepted
    modeld_accepted_on = get_object_or_404(ModelD, pk=modeld_id)
    
    for modela in q_2 :
        print(modela)
        if modela.id not in modela_set:
            modela_set.add(modela.id)

            latest_point = None
            modela_completed = 0
            for in_modela in modela.modelb_set.filter(user=request.user.userprofile):
                
                if latest_point is None or in_modela.created_at > latest_point:
                    latest_point = in_modela.created_at

                modela_completed = 0

                if latest_point is not None and latest_point > modeld_accepted_on.accepted_on:
                        modela_completed = 1 #<--- I want to be able to verify if modela_completed = 1 in my template.

                        print(f'Points for modela- {in_modela.venue} - {modela_completed}')

            
    return render(request,"template.html", {'modeld_accepted_on':modeld_accepted_on,'modela_completed':modela_completed,'modela_count':modela_count,'loyalty_card_latest':loyalty_card_latest, 'modelc':modelc,'q_2 ':q_2 })
```

**template**

```
{%for modela in q_2 %}

        {%for in_modela in modela.modelb_set.all%}
 
{{modela_completed}} #<-- this equals to zero on every occasions
    
        {%endfor%}

{%endfor%}
```

Following an example like this, how do I can I test if `modela_completed=1`? It seems whatever I try `modela_completed=None` because this is where the variable is first mentioned in the view.

When I print the  views values on the console I get a different result than what the template shows.

Comment: `q = Model.objects.all` Presumably you meant to put parentheses `.all()`, otherwise you are not actually calling the function...

Comment: `{'q ':q , 'p':p}` Is this code correct?  `'q '` has a trailing space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here is the solution I put together.

It feels a bit complicated, so I am sure there is room for improvement.

created a dictionary 'template_modela_completed'.

```
template_modela_completed = {} #<-- this goes at the top of the function before any logic
```

and added this at the bottom of the forloop:

```
template_modela_completed[modela.id] = modela_completed 

def function(request, modeld_id):

    q_1 = ModelD.objects.get(pk=modeld_id)
    q_2 = q_1.name.modela.all()
    
    #count the number of q_2  in modelc
    modela_count = q_2 .count()
    
    modela_set = set()
    sum_completed = 0
    template_modela_completed = {} #<-- ADDED HERE
    modeld_accepted_on = get_object_or_404(ModelD, pk=modeld_id)
    
    for modela in q_2 :
        print(modela)
        if modela.id not in modela_set:
            modela_set.add(modela.id)

            latest_point = None
            modela_completed = 0
            for in_modela in modela.modelb_set.filter(user=request.user.userprofile):
                
                if latest_point is None or in_modela.created_at > latest_point:
                    latest_point = in_modela.created_at

                modela_completed = 0

                if latest_point is not None and latest_point > modeld_accepted_on.accepted_on:
                        modela_completed = 1 #<--- I want to be able to verify if modela_completed = 1 in my template.

                        print(f'Points for modela- {in_modela.venue} - {modela_completed}')
template_modela_completed[modela.id] = modela_completed #<-- ADDED HERE

            
    return render(request,"template.html", {'modeld_accepted_on':modeld_accepted_on,'modela_completed':modela_completed,'modela_count':modela_count,'loyalty_card_latest':loyalty_card_latest, 'modelc':modelc,'q_2 ':q_2 })
```

Finally in the template I simply looped over the dictionary list and used an if statement to only show the `key` to the relevant `modela.id`.

```
{%for modela in q_2 %}

{% for key, value in template_modela_completed.items %} 
{%if key == venue.id and value == 1 %} 
 
{{modela.id}} is completed!
{%elif key == venue.id and value == 0 %}
{{modela.id}} is NOT completed!
%endif%}
{%endfor%}
{%endfor%}

{%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 1):

`{% if p == 1 %}` is the correct test.

In your specific code, there is the additional requirement that the two enclosing `for` loops are non-empty.

As a basic debugging test, you can put `<p>This is p: {{p}}</p>` in the template, outside of any loops, to see the value of p.

You could also `print(p)` in the view.

Comment: This is my problem. If I print the views on the console, it returns the right answer `p=1` but in the template it returns `p=none`  in all cases.

Comment: @PhilM Can you show the full template?  The posted template will only print `p` if it is equal to 1, therefore there must be parts of the template you haven't shown.

Comment: Hi @John-gordon, sorry for the late reply. I added the full template, but also added the full view (as you will see the code has changed as I tried to keep it as simple as possible when I asked my question, which when I think about it is probably why you couldnt see what was wrong with it. (thanks for sticking around!).